How can I set up an alert or beeping sound when my code breaks? (In Python ideally)
I am running some code for a robot, and it will keep running until I manually kill the process. OR if the code unexpectedly hits an error like a syntax error or other such errors/exceptions and crashes out.
I was wondering if it is possible to set up some alerting or beeping noise when my code crashes out.
My aim is to look away from my screen and only check it if the process has stopped running. If there are any other common ways to achieve the above, that would be great!
I can set up a beeping noise using python libraries, but the challenge is to get it executing, when the code breaks out unexpectedly.

Well you can definitely write a script that monitors a process, and if the process terminated emits a sound. I would split the task in two parts: how to monitor a process in python and how to emit a internal speaker beep in python.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384477/catching-an-exception-for-the-entire-script-in-python

I was wondering if it is possible to is typically an off-topic question for stack overflow. write some code and if you're stuck you'll get some help here

Thank you for the feedback, I will write some code and add it to the question. I was completely stuck on this one, but with the answer below I will attempt to put something together

First of all I would wrap your code into a main function if it isn't already, for neatness and other reasons I won't get into here. Then on your
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()

statement before you start the program do this:
try:
   main()
except Exception as e:
   do_bleep()
   raise e

This way you get your bleeping sound and then still get the exception like normal

Super helpful, thank you.
One question, if the code breaks several layers down from main(), but the Exception still be hit?

@dzdsds yes. Python will try run the function and if any error occurs, provided it isn't caught by another try-except statement within those layers, it will do the bleep

You can just use a try and except statements when your code breaks.
An example:
from playsound import playsound
try:
    print("blah blah blah")
    variable += 1
except:
    playsound("beep.mp3")

Remember to hook up the try command with every thing you have coded right now.
